# .NET MVC - Data missing from view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I would appreciate if you could help me solve my issue:

I have the following SQL table:

```
id | name | type(bool) | firmtypeid(integer) | isdeleted(bool)
1  | A    |   1        | 1                   | 0
2  | B    |   0        | 1                   | 0
```

Both 'type' and 'firmtypeid' is currently used in my code. However, I now want to get rid of 'type' and use only 'firmtypeid'. Hence, I would like my view to show both items. Currently, my view shows only the items with type=1 and I cannot find where this is used. I will post parts of my code below. I would appreciate if you could show me how to fix it.

**Controller**

```
public class FirmController : BaseController
{
    [Action(Roles = "viewtransportfirms")]
    public ActionResult Index()

        FirmsListViewModel _model = new FirmsListViewModel();
        SetViewBag();
        return View(_model);
    }

    private void SetViewBag()
    {
        CrudOperationsViewModel crdModel = new CrudOperationsViewModel();
        crdModel.LanguageId = languageid;
        using (TransportationServiceClient serviceClient = new TransportationServiceClient())
        {
            ViewBag.countries = serviceClient.GetCountries(base.WSC, languageid).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.title, Value = s.countrycode.ToString() }).OrderBy(o => o.Text).ToList();
            ViewBag.firms = serviceClient.GetTransportationFirms(base.WSC, languageid,1).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.firmname, Value = s.firmname.ToString() }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Currencies = addDefaultSelectItem(serviceClient.GetCurrencies(WSC).Select(q => new SelectListItem { Text = q.Text, Value = q.Value }).ToList());
            ViewBag.CurrencyDates = addDefaultSelectItem(serviceClient.GetCurrencyDateTypes(WSC, languageid).Select(q => new SelectListItem { Text = q.Name, Value = q.CurrencyDateTypeId.ToString() }).ToList());
        }
        using (PurchaseServiceClient purchaseClient = new PurchaseServiceClient())
        {

            ViewBag.Paymentterms = addDefaultSelectItem(purchaseClient.GetPaymentTerms(WSC, crdModel).Select(q => new SelectListItem { Text = q.name, Value = q.id.ToString() }).ToList());

        }
    }
```

**FirmsListViewModel**

```
public class FirmsListViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "firmname", ResourceType = typeof(ResourcePurchase))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "validation_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceValidation))]
    public string firmname { get; set; }

    public bool type { get; set; }

    public bool? isdeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**GetTransportationFirms**

```
public IList<FirmsListViewModel> GetTransportationFirms(WSCredential WSC, int languageId, int firmTypeId)
{
    Transportation transportation = new Transportation();
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(WSC.culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    return transportation.getFirms(languageId, firmTypeId);
}
```

**Transportation**

```
public class Transportation
{
    public kisanEntities _db = new kisanEntities();

    public Transportation()
    {

    }

    public IList<FirmsListViewModel> getFirms(int languageId, int firmTypeId)
    {

        return _db.agentandproducers.Where(s => s.isdeleted == false && s.type == true && s.firmtypeid == firmTypeId).Select(q => new FirmsListViewModel()
        {
            name = q.firmname,
            isdeleted = q.isdeleted,
            type = q.type,
            id = q.id,
        }).ToList();

    }
}
```

What I did is the following:
1- I removed the `s.type == true` from the last part of the code and made the following change:

```
public IList<FirmsListViewModel> getFirms(int languageId, int firmTypeId)
{

    return _db.agentandproducers.Where(s => s.isdeleted == false && s.firmtypeid == firmTypeId).Select(q => new FirmsListViewModel()
    {
        name = q.firmname,
        isdeleted = q.isdeleted,
        type = q.type,
        id = q.id,
    }).ToList();

}
```

However, `ViewBag.firms` still only displays the firms with `type=1` in the browser.

What else may be wrong? How can I fix the issue? Any help is appreciated!

**Edit - View is below**:

```
@using System.Net.Mime
@model kisanViewModels.FirmsListViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    SelectListItem showAllListItem = new SelectListItem { Text = kisanResources.App_GlobalResources.ResourceCommon.showAll, Value = "-1" };
    List<SelectListItem> lstCountries = ViewBag.countries;
    List<SelectListItem> lstFirms = ViewBag.firms;
    lstCountries.Insert(0, showAllListItem);
    lstFirms.Insert(0, showAllListItem);
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink(kisanResources.App_GlobalResources.ResourcePurchase.add_firm, "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firmname)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.firmname, lstFirms, new { @class = "form-control select2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.firmname)

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.countrylabel)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.firmcountry, lstCountries, new { @class = "form-control select2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.firmcountry)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12" id="">

        <div class="portlet light ">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="fa fa-building font-red-sunglo"></i>
                    <span class="caption-subject font-red-sunglo bold uppercase">@Html.Raw(kisanResources.App_GlobalResources.ResourcePurchase.firms)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs">
                    <div class="portlet-input input-inline input-small" style="text-align:right">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="portlet-body" id="firms_wrap">
                @{Html.RenderAction("GetFirms", new { firmname = "-1", country = "-1", });}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@section styles{

    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@section scripts{

    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/pages/scripts/components-select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In an Index action method you initialize an array of `FirmsListViewMode`, but pass a single `FirmsListViewModel` instance to a View.

Comment: Its hard to understand what your doing here. In the GET method you initialize `model` to your collection of `FirmsListViewModel` but then never use it and just throw it away. Then you set `_model` to an empty collection of `FirmsListViewModel` and return that to the view.

Comment: Dear koryakinp and Stephen Muecke, I corrected the code according to your comments. model was used in my old code. Now, only _model is used. However, I still have the same problem in my original question.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `ViewBag.firms` to render the data in your view? Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your `SetViewBag` method and check the value assigned to the `ViewBag.firms`?

Comment: @SQLfreaq. Even after your edit, your code is not making sense. Why are you passing an empty `FirmsListViewModel` to the view when you also passing a whole lot of SelectLists that have no relationship to `FirmsListViewModel`. And your using a view model so why in the world are your using all that awful `ViewBag`. Your view model should contain `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties for generating your dropdownlists

Comment: And if your have removed `s.type == true` from your query, then your query will show records that have both `type=true` and `type=false`

Comment: dear IPValverde, I posted my cshtml code. I am using Viewbag in my dropdown list. Dear Stephen, I am very new to .NET MVC. I know that this is not professional coding. I just want to solve the issue at hand before converting the code to the right format.

Comment: @SQLfreaq. To notify a use you need to include their user name in the comment - as this message starts (and you can only notify one user at a time). The code in your last snippet does work, so either your not using it or you have shown the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, after spending so much time on this, I realized that the

```
public IList<FirmsListViewModel> getFirms(int languageId, int firmTypeId)
{}
```

method was on my WCF service and the WCF service reference was pointing at a different location other than my localhost. That's why the changes that I made on the getfirms method were not implemented.